# How to prevent jQuery mobile button's glow effect overlap other button

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I want to display my buttons with permanent glow effect:

```
        <button type="button" class="ui-focus">test</button>
```

but the buttons' glowes are overlapping other buttons:

[image]

How can I make glows appear at the same z-index?

Comment: can you post more code ?, just I need to know how you list these buttons

Comment: please wait a minute, I'll put it online

Comment: Here it is: https://aktos-elektronik.com/test/#demos and here its full source code: https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-website

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your css

```
.push-button button{
z-index:999;
}
```

Just pop the buttons out.

Comment: I tried this one in the first place but it doesn't work somehow.